# What kind of clothing did epic and purana characters wear?

Tags: puranas, smriti

Please mention the sanskrit words/titles for clothes, Are there instances where kind, type of clothing should be used is discussed? Or even in suggestive types in puranas?

Like gods wearing clothes, characters wearing clothes, names, kind, type given about clothes?

Comment: Clothing in general? Or are you looking for something specific?

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto in general, what kind of clithes are mentioned in puranas worn by characters as well as clothes suggested for humans.

Comment: @sv. Yeah, but other instances in puranas, describing the clothes of characters, in ithasas and puranas.

Comment: @sv. Did it now.